# Control another app with cocoa

Tags: cocoa, controls, terminal

I have an app that runs a binary executable in terminal using

```
NSString *systemRun = [[NSString alloc] init];
systemRun = [systemRun stringByAppendingFormat:@"open -a Terminal %@", executable];
system([systemRun UTF8String]);
```

Now, I want to put an "End" button on my GUI and that will close Terminal. However, before I can use NSRunningApplication stuff to terminate it, I need to make the Terminal session log out so it won't prompt the user with a warning saying that the login process is still running. I figure it'd be easiest just to make the window type "logout" and a return character. I know I can do this with AppleScript, but it seems odd that AppleScript could do something that Cocoa can't. Am I missing something?

Comment: For the meantime, using the `forceTerminate` method instead of `terminate` works fine, but general answers on how to do this will still be greatly appreciated and very helpful for the rest of my app.

Comment: **GO!**

You should consider yourself god of your computer.  Unfortunately, malicious people have surrounded us with bars.  AppleScript does NOT send objective-C messages to the receiving program.  It sends events which the recipient agrees to interpret and perform.

The debugger and the program called "Instruments" is proof that such a thing can be done.  I tend to think that the receiving program would have to be executed within the heap of the caller.  Multiple copies of a programming running simultaneously was never Apple's way.  Who owns my computer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**STOP!**

You should *never* tell another application to quit if the user might already have been using it outside of the context of your program's use of that application.

If your user already has a terminal window open and doing something, then your program will interfere with that when it tries to kill Terminal.app. If the user has Terminal.app configured to not prompt before closing a session that is only running the login process and shell, then you will end up killing all the user's ssh sessions without warning.

(How would you like it if your word processor told your web browser to display a page, and then killed all your browser sessions when you closed the one page?)

At the very least, use `open -n -W -a`, but if possible, don't use Terminal at all, and just pipe your executable's stdout to an NSTextView. If your executable needs to interact with the user, then consider using an `xterm` process, which will terminate on its own when your process finishes.

Comment: Ah, xterm is a good idea. Unfortunately, I made this awesome GUI wrapper to run the executable in but I had to strip the idea because a couple buffering and encoding problems that came up every so often. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

**GO!**

You should consider yourself god of your computer.  Unfortunately, malicious people have surrounded us with bars.  AppleScript does NOT send objective-C messages to the receiving program.  It sends events which the recipient agrees to interpret and perform.

See OSX Distributed Objects Architecture using NSDistantObject, NISInvocation, NSConnection, NSPortMessage, NSPort to transmit message from client process to server process.  I have yet to traverse the path.

See [Distributed Objects](http://pooh.poly.asu.edu/Mobile/Resources/ObjectiveC/doc/GNUStep/docs/Developer/Base/ProgrammingManual/manual_7.html) manual.